# Coloring a river on a grayscale image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

Trying to paint a river from black to yellow and I'm having a "small" issue.

The image that given on this problem is a simple grayscale image of a map where there's a river on it ([original image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s7jHX.png)).
The task is to "paint" this river from black (0,0,0) to yellow (255,255,0).

As far as I know, we can't actually paint grayscale images without "converting" it to RGB so what I did:

1. Got the image,
2. "Read" the image with *imread()*,
3. Used the function *cat* to concatenate my image (and apparently "turn" into a RGB image?),
4. Looped through each part of my image and checked which ones had values between 0 and 48 (according to what I read there are different shades of black and apparently it goes from 8 to 8 like (0,0,0), (8,8,8) and so on)
5. If there was a value within that range, I'dd color it yellow (255,255,0)

The problem is that not only the river was painted yellow but a relatively large yellow square has been added to the right side of the image. I'll post the image right after the code.

```
originalIM_River = imread('fig_lista4_2.bmp');
figure,title('Original image'),imshow(originalIM_River)

imRGB_River = cat(3, originalIM_River, originalIM_River, originalIM_River);
[nLine, nColumn] = size(imRGB_River);

for i = 1 : nLine
    for j = 1 : nColumn
        if imRGB_River(i,j) >= 0 && imRGB_River(i,j) <= 48
            imRGB_River(i,j,:) = [255,255,0]; % (255,255,0) is yellow
        end
    end
end

figure, title('New imagem - River painted with yellow'),imshow(imRGB_River)
```

[River painted with yellow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iFqKs.png)

I've tried to separate each channel from the image (red , green, blue), find which pixels were within the range of 0 to 48 and paint it yellow to later concatenate them but that didn't work either.

Comment: I know nothing about Matlab but I guess you created an image 3x the original width when you `cat`ed two extra channels. I mean your image got wider in terms of pixels rather than deeper in terms of channels.

Comment: @MarkSetchell Indeed. I've checked the left side of my MatLab window and noticed it went from 1024x1026 to 1024x2591x3, trying to figure out what to do to fix it.

Comment: I guess your original image is already RGB, not single channel. So you probably need to just use a single channel with `originalIM_River(:,:,1)` or force `imread()` to load in greyscale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error lies with this line:

```
[nLine, nColumn] = size(imRGB_River);
```

Here `imRGB_River` is a 3-dimensional matrix, with 3 as the size of the third dimension. Since you only request 2 dimensions from the [`size`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/size.html) function it will return the *product* of all non-singleton trailing dimensions in the last output, so `nColumn` will be returned as `N*3`, or three times bigger than you were expecting. To fix it, you could either use your original image matrix (before replicating the third dimension):

```
[nLine, nColumn] = size(originalIM_River);
```

Or call `size` as follows to [ignore additional output dimensions](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/ignore-function-outputs.html):

```
[nLine, nColumn, ~] = size(imRGB_River);
```