# How to transmit Image to bits and back in MATLAB

Tags: image, matlab

I am trying to transmit a small **.jpg** figure. I am using the following line to convert the picture to bits:

```
pic = imread('****.jpg');
x = reshape((dec2bin(typecast(pic(:),'uint8'),8)-'0').',1,[]);
```

And then, I am trying the following to reconstruct the image:

```
n = 250;
m = 250;
s = num2cell(reshape(x,8,[])',2);
b = cellfun(@(x) bin2dec(strrep(num2str(x),' ','')), s);
out = reshape(b,n,m);
```

I am getting this error message:

```
Error using reshape
To RESHAPE the number of elements must not change.
Error in transmit_pic (line 13)
out = reshape(b,n,m);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: n is undefined by your code, you wrote m twice

Comment: @Veltz you are right. I just corrected the code.

Answer (score 0):

After tinkering a little bit I found a workaround. The problem was the bit depth.

Here is the correct code:

```
pic = imread('***.png');

x = reshape((dec2bin(pic,8)-'0').',1,[]);
[m, n] = size(pic);

s = num2cell(reshape(x,8,[])',2);
b = cellfun(@(x) bin2dec(strrep(num2str(x),' ','')), s);
out=reshape(b,m,n);  

image(out)
```

Comment: I'm guessing your issue was that the image was RGB (i.e. it was M-by-N-by-3), and you weren't taking into account the 3rd dimension. Using the line `[m, n] = size(pic);` does that for you, since `n` will contain the product of all trailing non-singleton dimensions (i.e. `N*3`). A little more explanation can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47444748/52738).

Comment: @gnovice you are absolutely correct. Thank you for the explanation.